# Upload image with Kartik file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

Hello i am trying to make the file upload to work but i dont know how to trigger the upload button.

I am using: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput

My Code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
         <input id="input-0a" class="file" type="file" data-allowed-file-extensions='["jpg", "png", "gif", "tiff", "bmp"]'>
     </div>
</form>
```

and the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

       // CATCH RESPONSE
      $("#input-0a").on('fileloaded', function(event, file, previewId, index) {
            alert('i = ' + index + ', id = ' + previewId + ', file = ' + file.name);
      });

        });
    </script>
```

When the file is loaded i get all the data. But how do i trigger the upload button?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#input-0a").on('fileloaded', function(event, file, previewId, index) {
        alert('i = ' + index + ', id = ' + previewId + ', file = ' + file.name);
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$("#input-0a").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "url to upload",
}).on("filebatchselected", function (event, files) {
    // trigger upload method immediately after files are selected
    $("#input-0a").fileinput("upload");
});
```

Comment: it does not work...is this method triggering the upload button?